# Phase 10 Twist, If I lay down a phase how will I get enough cards to continue?

Tags: phase-10

I was given Phase 10 Twist as a gift.

Most of the rules seem straight forward enough, but when trying to play it I'm confused on one point.

There came a time I laid down a phase and had 5 cards left. When my turn came I drew one card and discarded one as you are supposed to, but I still only had 5 cards.

How am I supposed to get enough cards to complete the next phase if every time I have to draw one card and discard one?

The rules aren't making any sense on that to me.

Answer (score 2):

After you complete a phase you must get rid of all the cards in your hand by hitting on existing Phases and discarding cards you can't play. Once someone who has completed a phase runs out of cards the hand is over and all the cards are dealt out again and players who completed the Phase can move on to the next Phase.

Answer (score 2):

During a round you can only ever work on the Phase that you started the round with. The round ends once someone has gotten rid of all of the cards in their hand by completing their phase and playing their remaining cards, if any, on other completed phases. Once a round is over your pieces will move and you have a new phase to work on for the next round. For example;

All players are working on Phase 1. Player 1 completes the phase but still has cards left. That player cannot attempt to work on Phase 2 until the following round when they are actually on the space for that Phase.